# How to use multiple timer capture Interrupt in stm32

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, interrupt, capture

ı have two capture interrupts from tim1ch1 and tim4ch1, when ı worked with only tim1 ch1, ı could use `if (htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)` but what if ı want to use tim4ch1 interrupts at the same time. Can ı use below format? is it correct or not? Can you warn me about it. I will not be able to try it as software that so ı want to ask professions about these kind of topics.

```
void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
    if (htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1) {
        if (htim->Instance == htim1.Instance) {
           // to do sth
        } 
    else if (htim->Instance == htim4.Instance) {
         // to do sth
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you won't be able to try it as a software? You write your software blind, without testing? Sounds like a problem waiting to happen, even if you know what you're doing. Test it on some dev board with the same MCU, anything is better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very strange way to handle this. The ISR tells you which timer raised an interrupt. You don't need to inspect the structure to figure it out.

You probably want something more like:

```c
void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
    if (htim == &htim1)
    {
        // handle TIM1 interrupts
    }
    else if (htim == &htim4)
    {
        // handle TIM4 interrupts
    }
}
```

Each of those "handle" sections can test which channel caused the interrupt. If you only enabled interrupts you care about, there's probably nothing to check.

Comment: For both timers(TIM1 and TIM4), ı have  input capture direct channels  (Ch1) and  input capture indirect (Ch2) channels.  I activated global interrupt and ı started to channels with      
HAL_TIM_IC_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);   // main ch
HAL_TIM_IC_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);   // indirect ch
HAL_TIM_IC_Start_IT(&htim4,TIM_CHANNEL_1); HAL_TIM_IC_Start(&htim4,TIM_CHANNEL_2);
So ı have to define on the capture interrupt section as channel 1 like (if (htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)), ı need to use direct channels. So that ı had to have use that code block. Is it wrong?